# How to implementing conditional bijectors in Tensorflow (mainly a how to use a kwargs question as that gets me an error)

Tags: python, tensorflow2.0, keyword-argument

I'm trying to implement a conditional bijector.  That's not important what it is if you don't know, but essentially my code is this:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow_probability as tfp
from tensorflow_probability import distributions as tfd
import numpy as np
from math import log, exp
tfb = tfp.bijectors
import pickle as pk
import statsmodels.api as sm
import statsmodels.formula.api as smf
import pandas as pd
import os

class varFamBij2(tf.keras.models.Model):
    def __init__(self, *, output_dim, **kwargs): #** additional arguments for the super class
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.output_dim = output_dim
        num_bijectors = 5
        bijectors=[]
        for i in range(num_bijectors):
            bijectors.append(tfb.MaskedAutoregressiveFlow(tfp.bijectors.AutoregressiveNetwork(1, event_shape=self.output_dim, hidden_units=[32, 32], conditional=True, conditional_event_shape= 13)))
            bijectors.append(tfb.Permute(permutation=[1,0]))
        bijectors.append(tfb.MaskedAutoregressiveFlow(tfp.bijectors.AutoregressiveNetwork(1, event_shape=self.output_dim, hidden_units=[32, 32], conditional=True, conditional_event_shape= 13)))

        #A bijector is formed by chaining together many layers of bijectors
        self.bijector = tfb.Chain(bijectors)


          
x1 = tf.ones([2])
x2 = tf.ones([13])
mod11 = varFamBij2(output_dim=2)
predictions = mod11.bijector.forward(x1, conditional_input = x2)
```

`conditional_input = x2` is a kwarg.  Essentially I get this error:

```
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow_probability/python/bijectors/masked_autoregressive.py in call(self, x, conditional_input)
   1049       if self._conditional:
   1050         if conditional_input is None:
-> 1051           raise ValueError('`conditional_input` must be passed as a named '
   1052                            'argument')
   1053         conditional_input = tf.convert_to_tensor(

ValueError: 'conditional_input' must be passed as a named argument
```

The problem is the function `call(self, x, conditional_input)` has this conditional_input that is suppose to be fed in as a **kwargs per TF documentation (at least according to my very bad understanding of kwargs) and I think the **kwargs is not getting fed to conditional input as an argument (as the default value for conditional_input is None which is what I think is raising the error).

I don't think a super detailed knowledge of TensorFlow is necessary to answer this question.  I think my lack of being able to understand and work with kwargs is what is causing this program not to work.  Curious if someone can suggest the way to use kwargs (or another method) so that the call method will accept my conditional_input.  Thanks,

Cameron

Comment: you did everything right on the Python side, it looks like a bug in tfp. What version are you using?

Comment: I'm using the most recent version 2.3.0 (at least on colab).  I know conditional distributions weren't implemented two years ago, but I didn't get a not implemented error this time.

Comment: Please report a bug. It seems like chain [`._forward`](https://github.com/tensorflow/probability/blob/v0.11.1/tensorflow_probability/python/bijectors/chain.py#L289) is not passing kwargs correctly

Answer (score 1):

See this answer by SiegeLordEx on the TensorFlow Probability GitHub page. This resolved it: https://github.com/tensorflow/probability/issues/1159

Essentially one has to write this for conditional bijectors:

```
chain = Chain([Bijector1(name='b1'), Bijector2(name='b2')]) 
y = chain.forward(x, b1={'arg': 1}, b2={'arg': 2})
```